# Como guardar el resultado de una consulta en un txt desde terminal de linux con postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

estoy practicando con postgresql desde la terminal de linux, pero al momento de querer guardar el resultado de mi query en un archivo txt me aparece permiso denegado y no se a que se deba, ya intente con `chmod 766`  para dar permiso a mi carpeta y apesar de cambiar su permiso, sigue sin dejarme guardar el comando que ando utilizando es:

```
\o /home/cristian/Escritorio/Prueba/resultado.txt
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que en esa carpeta no tienes permisos, muy probablemente necesites permisos del usuario postgres para poder guardar el archivo. Intenta accediendo con su - postgres

Comment: como dice @DrakoRod es un problea de permisos, tienes que darle permisos al usuario postgres a esa ruta, si quieres puedes probar escribiendo el archivo en /tmp, ahi todos tienen permisos

Comment: Tienen toda la razon ambos muchas gracias @DrakoRod , Anthony Sotolongo, ya me permitio la salida mediante tmp, lo que tuve que hacer es darle todos los permisos a mis directorios mediante la instruccion chmod 777 * nombre_de_ la_carpeta y ya pude solucionar el error, les agradezco a ambos porque me guiaron a sacar el resultado gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo, primero me di cuenta que el comando para hacer la copia estaba mal, el correcto es `COPY (SELECT * FROM usuarios) to '/home/cristian/Escritorio/Prueba/resultado.txt' delimiter ',';`

y segundo tuve que darle permiso a las carpetas para que pudiera escribir el archivo con el comando `sudo 777 * **nombre_de_la_carpeta**`

Agradezco a @DrakoRod y a @Anthony Sotolongo los cuales me ayudaron a solucionar la problemática, dejo la solución por si a alguien mas le surge este error.